# BDD Serenity Jenkins consolidate multiple report into a single report

Tags: jenkins, serenity-bdd

I am using Serenity BDD for my project. I have divided feature files into different functional areas and they are in turn represented as separate Jenkins jobs. The problem I am facing is the Jenkins jobs generate separate report and the client requires a single report. I was wondering if somebody has tried Jenkins Copy artifact + Serenity aggregate to consolidate reports into a single serenity report. It would be great if you can share may be another (alternate) simpler report to do it. Cheers